# ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 Sub Child Collection Convention

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I`m trying to create a get/patch/Post Action for a Sub Child Items for ODATA Controller

the Endpoint I want to create is
//odata/Documents(1)/Lines(1)/SubLines

Here is the Entity

```
public class Document{

[Key]
public int DocEntry { get; set; }
public int DocNum { get; set; }
List<DocLines> Lines
}
public class DocLines
{
 
public int DocEntry { get; set; }
    [Key]
public int LineNum { get; set; }
public string ItemCode { get; set; }
public List<DocSubLines> SubLines{get;set;}
}
public class DocSubLines{
public int DocEntry { get; set; }
 
public int BaseLineId{get;set;}
[Key]
public int LineNum{get;set;}
public string Field{get;set;}
}
```

Registration of EDM

```
public override void BuildGeneratedEdmModel( ODataConventionModelBuilder builder)
    {
        
        var testDocument = builder.EntityType<Document>();
        testDocument.HasKey(c => c.DocEntry);
        testDocument.HasMany(p => p.Lines).IsExpandable();
        
        var testDocuemntLine = builder.EntityType<DocLines>();
        testDocuemntLine.HasKey(c => c.DocEntry);
        testDocuemntLine.HasMany(p => p.SubLines).IsExpandable();
        var testDocuments=  builder.EntitySet<Document>("Documents");
    }
```

OdataControler

```
public class DocumentsController : ODataController
    {
        
        //odata/Documents working 
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQuerable<Document> Get()
        {
            return _context.Documents.AsQueryable();
        }


        //odata/Documents(1)/Lines working
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQuerable<DocumentLines> GetLinesFromDocument(int key)
        {
           ..
        }
 [EnableQuery]
        //odata/Documents(1)/Lines(1)/SubLines not working
        public IQueryable<DocSubLines> GetSubLinesFromDocument(int key)
        {
            ..
        }
```

the Endpoint I want to create as
//odata/Documents(1)/Lines(1)/SubLines

Comment: Could you please share what issue you are having? Or what you haven't make run?

Comment: GetSubLinesFromDocument should have the second key parameter for navigation property 'lines'.